# Iterador implementado a un metodo no funciona

Tags: javascript, angular

El código es este, lo estamos ideando para un curso de Javascript con implementado a Angular. Actualmente estamos en el modulo Vainilla del curso. La funcionalidad es crear un sistema de "deuda bancaria". El error surge en finDeMes que es un método creado para ver que funcione el método pago. Creo que el error surge por la declaración del `this`. finDeMes solo se está aplicando en el primer `array`. ¿Me podrian explicar porque sucede esto y decirme que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?.  Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
/**Clase Cliente */
class Cliente {
   dni;
   deudaOriginal;
   deudaActual;
   pagos = [];

   constructor(dni, deudaOriginal, deudaActual) {
      this.dni = dni;
      this.deudaOriginal = deudaOriginal;
      this.deudaActual = this.deudaOriginal;
   }
}
/**Modulo programa*/

class Programa {
   clientes = [];

   comenzar() {
      /**Declara 3 clientes de ejemplo*/
      let cliente1 = new Cliente(41193314, 2000);
      this.clientes.push(cliente1);

      let cliente2 = new Cliente(27077768, 8000);
      this.clientes.push(cliente2);

      let cliente3 = new Cliente(12345678, 150);
      this.clientes.push(cliente3);
   }
   //**Genera un valor aleatorio de 0 a deudaOriginal para */
   finDeMes(dni, monto) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.clientes.length; i++) {
         let dni = this.clientes[i].dni;
         let monto =
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.clientes[i].deudaOriginal) + 0;
         return this.pago(dni, monto);
      }
   }
   pago(dni, monto) {
      /**Habra que restar a deudaActual el monto de pago,
       * si la deudaActual es menor o igual a cero se procesara un error*/

      for (let i = 0; i < this.clientes.length; i++)
         if (
            dni == this.clientes[i].dni &&
            !(this.clientes[i].deudaActual <= 0)
         ) {
            this.clientes[i].deudaActual = this.clientes[i].deudaActual - monto;
            this.clientes[i].pagos.push(monto);
            return (
               'Pago de $' +
               monto +
               ' acreditado' +
               '\n' +
               'Su deuda actual es de $' +
               this.clientes[i].deudaActual
            );
         } else {
            return 'Accion invalida, no posee deuda';
         }
   }

   pagoTotal(dni) {
      /**Se realizara un pago del total de la deudaActual*/
      for (let i = 0; i < this.clientes.length; i++)
         if (dni == this.clientes[i].dni) {
            let monto = this.clientes[i].deudaActual;
            return this.pago(dni, monto);
         }
   }

   resumen(dni) {
      /**Devuelve la deuda actual del cliente*/
      for (let i = 0; i < this.clientes.length; i++)
         if (dni == this.clientes[i].dni) {
            return 'El cliente debe $' + this.clientes[i].deudaActual;
         }
   }
}

/**Inicializador de sesión. Agrega 3 clientes ejemplo y 3 pagos ejemplo*/
sesion = new Programa();
sesion.comenzar();
sesion.finDeMes();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, la verdad no entiendo muy bien el sentido de usar un return dentro de ese for, puesto que si quieres 'retornar' varios valores diferentes por cada instancia de clientes eso no es posible, puesto que el return siempre te va a retornar un solo valor, no puede retornar varios, ademas el return dentro de un ciclo for, while o do while hace las vecez de un break statement (por eso solo coge el primero), pero que es exactamente lo que deseas?, obtener los valores de esa operación aplicada a cada cliente usando el metodo finDeMes?, o que deseas?

Comment: Ojo, el hecho de decir 'El return solo puede retornar un solo valor' no quiere decir que no pueda retornar arreglos (ya que son considerados un solo valor para el return), así que ahí mas o menos ya tienes una pista de aquello que deberías hacer para lograrlo (si es este el comportamiento que buscas).

Comment: Sospecho que el lo usaba para que imprima en consola.

Comment: Espero que no... porque si es así por un lado tiene conocimientos de varias cosas que no tienen otros usuarios mas iniciantes... pero por otro, quien nunca vio un console.log a esas alturas?, vaya...

Comment: Pues, no lo usó en su código, pero bueno, puede pasar. Por si a caso lo dejé en mi respuesta. Lo único que no entiendo es por qué a `monto` se le suma 0, es el elemento neutro de la suma, el resultado será igual con o sin el.

Comment: Emmm ahora que lo pienso, estamos algo despistados, en la misma pregunta aparece un log de algo, así que si, el usuario tiene conocimientos de console.log xd.

Comment: el cero porque soy tonto por que mas. si estuve teniendo problemas con el console log y usaba el return como console log porque esa funcion me devolvia "undefined" al final de cada log correcto. Ya voy a hacer unos arreglos porque creo que los return estan dañando la función y vuelvo aqui a decir que tal las cosas.

Comment: Si quieres el código arreglado me dices y lo anexo a la respuesta. Simplemente quiero darte la posibilidad de que lo pienses tú. Por cierto, al for de pago le faltan las llaves. Y un consejo, en Javascript existen operadores que te ahorran tiempo, entre ellos tienes `+=`, ejemplo: `a += b` que equivale `a = a + b`, luego `-=`, `*=`, `/=` y otros más. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Assignment_Operators

Comment: si los conozco efectivamente a esos operadores, pero todavia no me sinto comodo al usarlos. Se que en breve voy a tener que dar el salto. Al final me di por vencido y hice que el codigo no tenga la parte de gestion de errores que era lo que causaba el problema. Y ahora ya funciona a mi gusto y todos los Clientes tienen su prueba finDeMes funcionando correctamente. Asi que hilo cerrado en fin. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cuando llamas a `return`, este interrumpe el ciclo y todo lo que siga después de él hasta el final de la función y devuelve el valor siguiente a él. Deberías quitarlo en el caso de `finDeMes()`, o usarlo cuando quieras devolver una variable.

Hay otras palabras claves que tienen lugar en bucles como lo son for, while y do while.

- `break`, interrumpe el ciclo, pero no retorna nada. Es decir, se saldrá del bucle, pero se seguirá con el código de fuera del ciclo.
- `continue`, interrumpe la iteración actual para pasar a la siguiente.

Pienso que tal vez creas que `return` sea el modo de imprimir en la consola. No es precisamente su función, simplemente la consola muestra en pantalla lo que devuelve la función con `return` cuando es llamada desde la consola. Hay un método que está hecho para ese fin, es `console.log()`, dentro de las llaves colocas el texto o la variable que quieras que se imprima.

Si tu intención es que las funciones siempre devuelvan algo, podrías considerar crear un método en `Cliente` que haga el trabajo interno de `finDeMes` y que este último, dentro de la iteración llame a ese método de cada uno de los Clientes. Lo positivo de esta manera es que no tendrás que iterar dentro del método pago para encontrar al cliente que estás buscando. Simplemente cada uno tendrá el mismo método pero solo se modificará a sí mismo.

Otro error que encuentro es que `finDeMes()` no hace uso de sus parámetros `dni` y `monto`, simplemente pasa de ellos, sería mejor que directamente no tenga parámetros, porque entran en conflicto con sus variables de nombres iguales a la hora de pasarlas a `this.pago()`.